# Are these two kernels isomorphic groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory, gap

We have a finitely presented, infinite group $\mathsf{B}$,
coming from a geometric topology problem (it is the quotient of a braid group for a genus 2 surface).

It is generated by elements
\begin{equation}
\{r_{11}, \, t_{11}, \,  r_{12}, \, t_{12}, \, r_{21}, \, t_{21}, \,
r_{22}, \, t_{22}, \, z \},
\end{equation}
subject to the following relations (here $[a, \, b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$):
\begin{equation*} 
\begin{aligned}
  & z^2=1 \\
 &  [r_{12}^{-1}, \, t_{12}^{-1}] \, t_{12}^{-1} \,
[r_{11}^{-1}, \, t_{11}^{-1}] \, t_{11}^{-1}\, (t_{11} \, t_{12}) =
z & \\  &  [r_{21}^{-1}, \, t_{21}] \; t_{21} \;
[r_{22}^{-1}, \, t_{22}] \, t_{22}\, (t_{22}^{-1} \, t_{21}^{-1})=
z^{-1} \\
 & \\
& [r_{11}, \, r_{22}]=1 &  & 
[r_{12}, \, r_{22}]=1 \\
 &  [r_{11}, \, r_{21}]=1 &
 &  [r_{12}, \, r_{21}]=
z^{-1}\,r_{21}\,r_{22}^{-1}\,z\,r_{22}\,r_{21}^{-1} \\
 &  [r_{11}, \, t_{22}]=1 &  & 
[r_{12}, \, t_{22}]=z^{-1} \\
 &  [r_{11}, \, t_{21}]=z^{-1} &  & 
[r_{12}, \, t_{21}]=[z^{-1}, \, t_{21}] \\
 & [r_{11}, \, z]=[r_{21}^{-1}, \, z] & 
&  [r_{12}, \, z]=[r_{22}^{-1}, \, z] \\
 & \\
 &  [t_{11}, \, r_{22}]=1 &  & 
[t_{12}, \, r_{22}]= t_{22}^{-1}\, z \, t_{22} \\
 &  [t_{11}, \, r_{21}]=t_{21}^{-1}\, z \, t_{21}
&  &  [t_{12}, \, r_{21}]= [t_{22}^{-1}, \, z] \\
&  [t_{11}, \, t_{22}]=1 &  & 
[t_{12}, \, t_{22}]=[t_{22}^{-1}, \, z] \\
 &  [t_{11}, \, t_{21}]=[t_{21}^{-1}, \, z] &
&  [t_{12}, \, t_{21}]=
t_{22}^{-1}\, z \, t_{22} \, z^{-1} \, t_{21} \, z \, t_{22}^{-1}\,z^{-1}
\,t_{22}\,t_{21}^{-1} \\
&  [t_{11}, \, z]=[t_{21}^{-1}, \, z] & 
&  [t_{12}, \, z]=[t_{22}^{-1}, \, z] \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Next, we  consider the two extra-special groups of order $32$, whose labels are $[32, \, 49]$ and $[32, \, 50]$ in GAP4 notation, and whose presentations are as follows:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathsf{G}(32, \, 49) = \langle \, & \mathsf{r}_1, \, \mathsf{t}_1, \,
\mathsf{r}_2,\, \mathsf{t}_2, \, \mathsf{z} \; |  \; \mathsf{r}_{j}^2 =
\mathsf{t}_{j}^2=\mathsf{z}^2=1, \\
& [\mathsf{r}_{j}, \, \mathsf{z}]  = [\mathsf{t}_{j}, \, \mathsf{z}]= 1, \\
& [\mathsf{r}_j, \mathsf{r}_k]= [\mathsf{t}_j, \mathsf{t}_k] = 1, \\
& [\mathsf{r}_{j}, \,\mathsf{t}_{k}] =\mathsf{z}^{- \delta_{jk}} \, \rangle
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathsf{G}(32, \, 50) = \langle \, & \mathsf{r}_1, \, \mathsf{t}_1, \,
\mathsf{r}_2,\, \mathsf{t}_2, \, \mathsf{z} \; |  \; \mathsf{r}_{1}^2 =
\mathsf{t}_{1}^2=\mathsf{z}^2=1, \; \mathsf{r}_{2}^2 =
\mathsf{t}_{2}^2=\mathsf{z}\\
& [\mathsf{r}_{j}, \, \mathsf{z}]  = [\mathsf{t}_{j}, \, \mathsf{z}]= 1, \\
& [\mathsf{r}_j, \mathsf{r}_k]= [\mathsf{t}_j, \mathsf{t}_k] = 1, \\
& [\mathsf{r}_{j}, \,\mathsf{t}_{k}] =\mathsf{z}^{- \delta_{jk}} \, \rangle
\end{split}
\end{equation}
There are two surjective group homomorphisms $$\varphi_{49} \colon \mathsf{B} \to \mathsf{G}(32, \, 49), \quad \varphi_{50} \colon \mathsf{B} \to \mathsf{G}(32, \, 50),$$ expressed in both cases by
$$[r_{11}, \; t_{11}, \; r_{12}, \; t_{12}, \; r_{21}, \; t_{21}, \; r_{22}, \; t_{22}, \; z] \mapsto [\mathsf{t_2}, \; \mathsf{t}_1, \; \mathsf{t}_1 \mathsf{r}_2, \; \mathsf{r}_1, \; \mathsf{t}_2 \mathsf{r}_1, \; \mathsf{r}_2, \; \mathsf{t}_1, \; \mathsf{t}_2, \; \mathsf{z}].$$
Let us denote their kernels by $\mathsf{K}_{49}$ and $\mathsf{K}_{50}$, respectively.

> **Question.** Are $\mathsf{K}_{49}$ and $\mathsf{K}_{50}$ isomorphic groups?

I have constructed $\mathsf{K}_{49}$ and $\mathsf{K}_{50}$  by using GAP4, and I tried to make some calculations on them. Unfortunately, GAP4 does not work with infinite groups so well as it works with finite groups, so the computational approach seems to be difficult (at least for me). The usual invariants that I was able to compute  ($\mathtt{AbelianInvariants}$, $\mathtt{MaximalAbelianQuotient})$ were not useful in order to distinguish them.

**Edit:** Here is the GAP4 code I used in order to construct the group $\mathsf{B}$ and the two kernels.

```
ColorPrompt(true);

#redefine commutators
comm:=function(x, y) return x*y*x^-1*y^-1; end;

#Construction of the Group B
F:=FreeGroup("r11", "t11", "r12", "t12", "r21", "t21", "r22", "t22", "z");;
r11:=F.1;; t11:=F.2;; r12:=F.3;; t12:=F.4;;
r21:=F.5;; t21:=F.6;; r22:=F.7;; t22:=F.8;; z:=F.9;;

U:=z^2;;
S1:=comm(r12^(-1), t12^(-1))*t12^(-1)*comm(r11^(-1), t11^(-1))*t12*z^(-1);;
S2:=comm(r21^(-1), t21)*t21*comm(r22^(-1), t22)*t21^(-1)*z;;
R1:=comm(r11, r22);;
R2:=comm(r11, r21);;
R3:=comm(r11, t22);;
R4:=comm(r11, t21)*z;; 
R5:=comm(r11, z)*comm(z, r21^(-1));;
R6:=comm(r12, r22);;
R7:=z^(-1)*r21*r22^(-1)*z*r22*r21^(-1)*comm(r21, r12);;
R8:=comm(r12, t22)*z;;
R9:=comm(r12, t21)*comm(t21, z^(-1));;
R10:=comm(r12, z)*comm(z, r22^(-1));;
T1:=comm(t11, r22);;
T2:=comm(t11, r21)*t21^(-1)*z^(-1)*t21;;
T3:=comm(t22, t11);;
T4:=comm(t11, t21)*comm(z, t21^(-1));;
T5:=comm(t11, z)*comm(z, t21^(-1));;
T6:=comm(t12, r22)*t22^(-1)*z^(-1)*t22;;
T7:=comm(t12, r21)*comm(z, t22^(-1));;
T8:=comm(t12, t22)*comm(z, t22^(-1));;
T9:=t22^(-1)*z*t22*z^(-1)*t21*z*t22^(-1)*z^(-1)*t22*t21^(-1)*comm(t21, t12);;
T10:=comm(t12, z)*comm(z, t22^(-1));;

B:=F/[U, S1, S2, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, R10, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10];;
r11:=B.1;; t11:=B.2;; r12:=B.3;; t12:=B.4;;
r21:=B.5;; t21:=B.6;; r22:=B.7;; t22:=B.8;; z:=B.9;;

   
#construction of G(32, 49) 
f:=FreeGroup("r1", "t1", "r2", "t2", "s");
r1:=f.1;; t1:=f.2;; r2:=f.3;; t2:=f.4;; s:=f.5;;
g:=f/[r1^2, t1^2, r2^2, t2^2, s^2, comm(r1, s), comm(t1, s), comm(r2, s), comm(t2,s),
comm(r1, r2), comm(t1, t2), comm(r1, t1)*s, comm(r1, t2), comm(r2, t1), comm(r2, t2)*s];;
r1:=g.1;; t1:=g.2;; r2:=g.3;; t2:=g.4;; s:=g.5;;
IdSmallGroup(g); StructureDescription(g);
    

#construction of the group homomorphism B->G(32, 49)
hom49:=GroupHomomorphismByImages(B,g,[r11, t11, r12, t12, r21, t21, r22, t22, z],
[t2, t1, r2*t1, r1, r1*t2, r2, t1, t2, s]);
K49:=Kernel(hom49); 
    

#construction of G(32, 50);
o:=FreeGroup("u1", "v1", "u2", "v2", "y");
u1:=o.1;; v1:=o.2;; u2:=o.3;; v2:=o.4;; y:=o.5;;
h:=o/[u1^2, v1^2, u2^2*(y^-1), v2^2*(y^-1), y^2, comm(u1, y), comm(v1, y), comm(u2, y), comm(v2,y), comm(u1, u2), comm(v1, v2), comm(u1, v1)*y, comm(u1, v2), comm(u2, v1), comm(u2, v2)*y];;
u1:=h.1;; v1:=h.2;; u2:=h.3;; v2:=h.4;; y:=h.5;;
IdSmallGroup(h); StructureDescription(h);
    

#construction of the group epimomorphism B->G(32, 50)
hom50:=GroupHomomorphismByImages(B,h,[r11, t11, r12, t12, r21, t21, r22, t22, z],
[v2, v1, u2*v1, u1, u1*v2, u2, v1, v2, y]);
K50:=Kernel(hom50);
```

Comment: You can ask GAP for a presentation of the kernels via `IsomorphismFpGroup`. However, since $B$ is infinite and the quotients are finite, the kernels will be infinite, too. So in general, I wouldn't expect a generic computation to be able to prove if they are isomorphic. If you are lucky, then indeed some invariant can distinguish them (you could try nilpotent quotients via the `nq` package). Your best hope likely is to try to exploit the structure of $B$ somehow. How exactly did you construct it?

Comment: Oh and for anybody willing to help you, it would tremendously help if you also provided the GAP code to enter $B$ and compute the two kernels. I certainly would play with it a bit if it was available, but I am not going to manually type in a presentation :-).

Comment: Regarding the group B, it comes from a geometric topology problem (it is the quotient of a braid group for a genus 2 surface).

Comment: @MaxHorn: You are absolutely right, I included the code. Thank you for the suggestion :-)

Comment: Even if the kernels have the same abelianization, you might say what this abelianization is?

Comment: @YCor: The abelianization in both cases is $\mathbb{Z}^8 \oplus (\mathbb{Z}_2)^4$.

Comment: OK. So in both case there's a characteristic subgroup of index $2^8$ in $K_i$ (mod out by derived subgroup of $K_i$, then by torsion, and then by squares, and keep the kernel). Maybe this is small enough to compute its abelianization? Also it's tempting to directly kill squares and keep the kernel, which now has index $2^{12}$ in $K_i$, it it's still amenable to computation.